# Test cases for Angular Components with Ngrx Store

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx-store, angular-test, ngrx-test

I want to write test case for the following .I have tried with the following code but didnt work at all.

Been Searching for this since few hours but no solution.

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.isDarkTheme$ = this.themeService.getDarkTheme();
        this.store.select(selectUser).subscribe((data) => {
          this.role = data.role.name;
          this.firstName = data.firstName;
          this.lastName = data.lastName;
          this.menuItems = menuItems(this.role);
        });
      }

describe('test', () => {
    it('should get userData from the store', () => {
      const role:string = "admin";
      const firstName:string = "Jim";
      const lastName:string = "Becker";
      const menuItems:MenuItems[] = [
        {
          key: 'dashboard',
          label: 'DASHBOARD',
          url: '/tiles/dashboard',
          icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-sign-out',
        },
        {
          key: 'teams',
          label: 'TEAMS',
          url: '/tiles/teams',
          icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-users',
        },
      ];
      const mockHomeState = store.overrideSelector(
        selectUser,
      menuItems
      );

      component.ngOnInit();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please provide us your effort as well. I very well understand that you need guidance but what you are asking is a solution (which comes under freelancing work). So, please update your question accordingly to avoid getting it closed soon

Comment: Updated with required code .Please do provide a solution if there's a  something that am missing